# Cannot update data fetched from an API when viewing on full screen on codepen

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, codepen

Probably I am dealing with a bug but take a look!
Here is my [pen](https://codepen.io/evangeloskolimitras/pen/oaywoW).

But when I change to Full page view the functionality does not work properly.
Everything works fine but the title with the full name does not!

Any ideas perhaps?

```
        .then(
        (data) => {
            img.src = data.picture.large
            image_title.innerHTML = data.name.first
            name.innerHTML = `${ data.name.title } ${ data.name.first } ${ data.name.last }`
            sex.innerHTML = ` ${ data.gender }` 
            if(data.gender === 'male') {
                console.log('boy')
                container.style.background = "#20232A"
            }else {
                console.log('girl')
                container.style.background = "#009688";
            }
            age.innerHTML = ` ${ data.dob.age }`
            city.innerHTML = ` ${ data.location.city }`
            post.innerHTML = ` ${ data.location.postcode }`
            state.innerHTML = ` ${ data.location.state }`
            country.innerHTML = ` ${ data.nat }`
            email.innerHTML = ` ${ data.email }`
        }
    )
```

Comment: Works fine for me on full page view. Chrome Mac... oh wait, I see the fullname doesn't update on full page view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've got a lot of variables declared in the global scope, and in particular one of them is called "name".  The symbol "name" is bound to the `window` object already as the name of the window.  The statement

```
const name = infos.querySelector("#full-name");
```

does not do what one might think. It looks like it should bind the variable `name` to the `<h2>` element; in fact what it does is set the window name to the string "[object HTMLHeadingElement]" (may vary by browser).

The best way to fix it in my opinion would be to sanitize all the code by wrapping it all in a dummy IIFE.  Add

```
(function() {
```

before the existing first line and

```
})();
```

after the last line, and it works, because all the code is now in a new private scope and nothing collides with `window` properties.  It also works if you change the variable from "name" to "xname" or anything else that doesn't collide with a built-in browser symbol.

Why does it work in the Codepen "Editor" view? I don't know the "deep" answer for this, but in Editor view the page your pen creates is tucked into an `<iframe>` element. Now the `<iframe>` element does have a "name" property, but mysteriously the declaration of your `name` constant is allowed to shadow that.  In "Full screen" view, your page is the actual top-level window, and in that situation `window.name` won't allow itself to be shadowed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok easy fix: 
https://codepen.io/geoidesic/full/EdRvGR/

Change 'full-name' to 'fullname'. Not sure why (see comments by Pointy) but easy work-around.

```
    <h1 class="title">Random User Generator</h1>
    <hr>

    <div id="content" class="container">
        <div class="container--info">
            <div id="imgContainer" class="container--info-imgContainer">
                <div class="image">
                    <img id="image" src="https://am3pap002files.storage.live.com/y4pWy8i6R2SB4wYy260mAfz0bItbMHzhUBps0ip7YWPD-gdqYRVbcANXyN68L_j3mnDBLeYEAHTaD83MDocM42zlZq8PkUYG0sYL7fDzK9_nCOAmsCs9nylgyN-TjYyGEqulmG2SYITb0VQ_v9_fbsXbEYdobbp3hsGQZz2GLfowMkdWg97yga-i13mzZi_K5Xf/20180912_172044.jpg?psid=1&width=1528&height=1890" alt="">
                    <div id="image-title" class="image-title toCapital">Evangelos</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container--info-details">
                <div id="infos" class="container--info-details--inner">
                        <h2 id="fullname" class="container--info-details--inner-header toCapital">evangelos kolimitras</h2>
                        <div class="container--info-details--inner-gender toCapital">Sex: <span id="sex">Male</span></div>
                        <div class="container--info-details--inner-age">Age: <span id="age">26</span></div>
                        <div class="container--info-details--inner-location">
                            <div class="container--info-details--inner-location--city toCapital">City: <span id="city">fellbach</span></div>
                            <div class="container--info-details--inner-location--postcode ">Post Code: <span id="post">70734</span></div>
                            <div class="container--info-details--inner-location--state toCapital">State: <span id="state">baden würrtemberg</span></div>
                            <div class="container--info-details--inner-location--country toCapital">Nationality: <span id="country">de</span></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="container--info-details--email">Email: <span id="email">evan@kol.de</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container--button">
            <div class="container--button-inner">
                <button class="btn" id="btn">Generate User</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



const url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/';

const container = document.querySelector('#content');
const button = document.querySelector('#btn');

/* Constants responsible for retrieving DOM elements from the Image Section */
const imgContent = document.querySelector('#imgContainer');
const img = imgContent.querySelector('#image');
const image_title = imgContent.querySelector('#image-title');

/* Variables responsible for retrieving DOM elements from the Infos Section*/
const infos = document.querySelector('#infos');
const name = infos.querySelector('#fullname');
const sex = infos.querySelector('#sex');
const age = infos.querySelector('#age');
const city = infos.querySelector('#city');
const post = infos.querySelector('#post');
const state = infos.querySelector('#state');
const country = infos.querySelector('#country');
const email = infos.querySelector('#email');



button.addEventListener(
    'click',
    () => {
        fetch(url)
        .then(handleErrors)
        .then( r => r.json() )
        .then(
            (res) => {
                const data = res.results[0];
                console.log(data);
                return data;
            }
        )

        /* DOM MANIPULATION */

        .then(
            (data) => {
                img.src = data.picture.large
                image_title.innerHTML = data.name.first
                full_name.innerHTML = `${ data.name.title } ${ data.name.first } ${ data.name.last }`
                sex.innerHTML = ` ${ data.gender }` 
                if(data.gender === 'male') {
                    console.log('boy')
                    container.style.background = "#20232A"
                }else {
                    console.log('girl')
                    container.style.background = "#009688";
                }
                age.innerHTML = ` ${ data.dob.age }`
                city.innerHTML = ` ${ data.location.city }`
                post.innerHTML = ` ${ data.location.postcode }`
                state.innerHTML = ` ${ data.location.state }`
                country.innerHTML = ` ${ data.nat }`
                email.innerHTML = ` ${ data.email }`
            }
        )

        .catch( (error) => { console.log(error) } )


        function handleErrors(response)  {
            if(!response.ok) {
                throw Error(response.status);
            };
            return response;
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: There's absolutely no reason that that change should make a difference; dashes are perfectly acceptable characters in "id" values.

Comment: Oh wait; yes there is: using `fullname` in JavaScript bypasses the `name` constant and goes straight to the binding implicitly created by the browser.

Comment: @Pointy could you explain that in other words please? Not sure how your two comments relate to one another.

Comment: The root of the problem is the global variable declared as "name".

Comment: so in other words name is be reserved by javascript or? Can you please point to a post or something so I can have a closer look?